# When to use “nachher noch”?

Tags: usage

What is implied by the expression *nachher noch*? In which cases is such term used?

e.g

> Hast du nacher noch Lust mit uns zu kochen?

Could the term "nachher noch" have been replaced by später?

Comment: It’s not a fixed expression. It’s just a combination of *nachher* and *noch*.

Comment: Was ist der Kontext? Gehen wir nachher noch zu Dir?

Comment: I understand it as "Would you like to look with us later (tonight)"? I do not understand the use of nachher noch though. can it be replaced by später?

Comment: why is this question voted down?

Comment: @Chin The answer by Thomas addresses this. *Später* misses the implicit reference to the activity before (e. g. cinema visit, some work, the addressed person just said, she has to complete, ...).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no, strictly speaking the meaning of "nachher noch" and "später" is not the same. To expand on why this is, read this example again:

> "Hast du **nachher noch** Lust mit uns zu kochen?"

Meaning: Do you **still** want to cook with us **later**? 
More literate translation: Do you, **- later, still** want to cook with us?

So assuming that you can replace "nachher noch" with "später" will result in the loss of what you would in English know as the word "still". This becomes much clearer when you know the expression "immer noch", which would mean "still still".

However, you are actually able to use "nachher" and "später" interchangeably, although the "nachher" *usually* gives you a slightly more precise indication of your time frame ("later that day"), whereas "später" simply means "later".

So "noch", in some sense, can refer to something that you do additionally (although usually not at the same time) such as in this case:

> "Person A: Ich bin fertig mit dem Putzen!"
>   
>   "Person B: Super! Kannst du **noch** die Wäsche waschen?"
>
> "Person A: I am done with all the cleaning!"
>   
>   "Person B: Super! Could you **also**/**additionally** do the laundry?

As Thomas has said, "noch" could also refer to things that you have already done in the past.

So to recap all of this, "noch" means "also/in addition" or can refer to something that has happened or you have experienced in the past, usually meaning "still".

Replacing "später" with the word "nachher" works, as long as you keep the word "noch". "Später noch" or "nachher noch" have slightly different meanings, due to the different precision of their time frames (recall "later" or "later, but today" respectively).

I hope this helps you not only understand the inital question you have asked, but how you can use these words effectively whilst knowing what they mean :)

Comment: I don't think this answer grasps the meaning of *noch* in this context correctly. While it can mean *still*, it then must be replacable by *immernoch*. In the given example you can not do that without changing the connotation behind the meaning.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I would argue that the answer I provided was beyond the scope of the question, intentionally taken beyond the context of the question to allow the owner of the question to be able to use the words in question even out of context. In his specific question, which I quoted, I set the translation of "nachher noch" in bold: "still... later". I agree that "still" on it's own, as mentioned later in my answer, is certainly out of context for that question for above mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The word "noch" refers to an other action which happened before. So the person asked might be tired or does not have any time left to join the company further. So it also opens the question to be negated. It is not so unfriendly to say "no" then.